# JavaScript FormData() access file body

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I have an HTML form with a file upload input. The form data is stored in a `FormData()` object so I can send it to the server using `AJAX`.

What I'm trying to do is access the `FormData()` values so I can modify the file contents that appear in the request. I have been monitoring the requests in `Web Developer Tools -> Network`.

If I'm uploading a `.txt` file or image, I want to be able to read its content, modify it and append it to the `FormData()`.

My code so far is able to show the File object but I have no clue how to access the contents.

```
for( var pair of myFormData.entries() ){

   /* pair[1] is the file object inside the FormData */
   console.log(pair[0], pair[1]);

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot read file content on the client side. It needs to be done on the server. But you can change the values with `myFormData.set(name, value)`

Comment: that's so weird, since I can read a selected file content using FileReader(), but what I need here is to read it from the FormData() object

Comment: Do it the other way around. Use `FileReader` to get the file contents, then add the modified contents to the `FormData` as a `Blob`.